# Is it possible to use the Mono scripting engine with Cake on Windows?

Tags: c#, cakebuild

I've only got Windows at the moment, but when running My Cake build scripts on TravisCI I've noticed some things differ between when running on Mono and it's scripting engine vs. running on Windows with Roslyn.

So to help troubleshooting these issues I'm wondering if it's possible to use the Mono scripting engine on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's certainly possible, just pass the `-mono` switch to Cake on Windows.